# Is there a way to edit the embedded checkout as used on an external site in BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm using the BigCommerce embedded checkout on an external site and want to know if there's a way to alter it?

I edited the theme files in the browser via the admin panel as well as following [this tutorial](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/customizing-checkout/checkout-sdk-quickstart) to edit the Checkout SDK. In each case the changes showed up on the checkout of my BigCommerce site but not on the embedded checkout of my external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An embedded checkout is rendered separately from the respective store's built-in checkout so changes made via the Checkout SDK aren't supported. The [Storefront Web APIs don't currently support CORS](https://github.com/bigcommerce/checkout-sdk-js#cors) and because of that this library only functions on BigCommerce storefronts.